# How to get an input field to cover two td's

Tags: html, css, input, html-table

I'm trying to create a very basic form.
I have a table with three td's. 
In my second row I would like my input to span 2 td's. Unfortunately I cannot for the life of me get the input field to cover two td's. I have tried `colspan="2"` in the td tag but it didn't seem to work.

```
    <table id="info_table">
            <tr>
                <td >Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="first_name" autofocus placeholder="First Name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td id="email" colspan="2"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex. example@example.ca"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually set the input field's width to 100%, like this:

```
<td id="email" colspan="2">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex. example@example.ca" style="width: 100%">
</td>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/t03s87rn/)

Manually setting the width to 100% ensures that it takes up all the space it can, rather than defaulting to the one column.

If you have a separate CSS file, you'll probably want to put `width: 100%` in the appropriate location in there (within `input{}` or something similar) to keep it separate from your HTML code.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

```css
td{
  padding:5px;
}
input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="info_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" autofocus placeholder="First Name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td id="email" colspan="2"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex. example@example.ca"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `input` a width so that it will expand

```css
td{
  padding:5px;
}
input{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="info_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="first_name" autofocus placeholder="First Name"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td id="email" colspan="2"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="ex. example@example.ca"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```